# Difference between "weird content" and "weirdly content"

Tags: meaning, differences, adverbs

What's the difference between *weird content* and *weirdly content*?

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, content is a noun, and so the descriptor is an adjective (weird).

"I'm reading this book about humans who morph into rats; there's some pretty **weird content** in there."

In your second case, content is an adjective, and so the descriptor must be an adverb (weirdly).

"When Bill's father died, he was **weirdly content**.  It was as if a mass had been lifted off of his shoulders, and he no longer had to constantly prove himself."

Comment: Good answer, but it could use examples.  For instance, weird content in a cookbook that has recipes from Mars.  Weirdly content:  think of a situation where someone shouldn't be happy with a situation but they are anyway.  Illustrations are worth an upvote.

Comment: +! for the grammatical explanation. But in your second example I would not agree that *weirdly* was an appropriate adverb. There is nothing *weird* about such a feeling. A lot of people in their sadness and grief experience a sense of new-found independence, when their parents pass.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, but for those people, it still might seem weird at the time.

Comment: @deadrat Excellent advice. Zabari: now a very nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those to make sense, you have to interpret them like so:

> weird content

Content here is a noun (CON-tent), meaning *that which is contained*—such as the content (text) of an article, for example. If an article is weird, it will have "weird content".

> weirdly content

Content here is an adjective (con-TENT), meaning *satisfied or at peace*. Someone who is content in a weird way—such as when the circumstances might normally lead to someone not being content—you might be able to describe them as "weirdly content". (I wouldn't encourage you to rush to use this expression, though, as it's a little odd.)